# Launch GUI from command line

Tags: raspberry-pi, window-manager, raspbian

My question is relatively simple, but I am a total Linux and Raspbian noob:

*How can I start programs with a GUI from a command line (on the default desktop!) on a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch?*

Currently, when I try to start a program with GUI from the command line, nothing happens, no error, but also no window (wmctrl shows there is only one desktop, so I am sure the programs don't appear on another desktop or something).

I have heard about and tried out XServer, but I don't understand and thus, am not able to utilise it.

Because I can see and use the Desktop, I guess I don't have to worry about installing a window manager.

Comment: You just run the program...

Comment: @psusi That obviously does not work, as I described in my question.

Comment: "Don't work" is not an error description.  What happens when you try?

Comment: I explained it really accuratley, actually. All programs behave like everything works normally, they dont show any error and continue execution normally, but the window does not appear.

Comment: Ok, no error, but you also don't return to the command prompt?  Are you running this from a terminal window inside the gui, or a tty?

Comment: @psusi Yeah, it's a terminal window inside of the GUI.